# Crossprod between the first column and other columns of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got the following working well for one column, but need to apply it to all columns. Each column `A01`, `A02` etc. needs to be multiplied with column `CAG` using `crossprod()`, and then each should be divided by the sum of that column

```
#My data frame
data <- data.frame(CAG = c(13, 14, 15), A01 = c(6485,35,132), A02 = c(0,42,56))

#Sum each column independently
sumcolumn <- colSums(data[ , 2:ncol(height)], na.rm=TRUE)

# Work with column A01
result <- crossprod(data$`A01`, data$CAG) / sumcolumn
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mat <- data.matrix(data)
c(crossprod(mat[, -1], mat[, 1])) / colSums(mat[, -1])
```

I don't think `na.rm` is a problem in `colSums`. Because if there is any `NA` in a column, the cross product will be `NA` in the first place.